# How do I upload a files to google app engine app when field name is not known

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have tried a few options, none of which seem to work (if I have a simple multipart form with a named field, it works well, but when I don't know the name I can't just grab all files in the request...).

I have looked at [Upload files in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81451/upload-files-in-google-app-engine) and it doesn't seem suitable (or to actually work, as someone mentioned the code snipped it untested).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation on the [Webob request object](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/reference.html#query-post-variables). File uploads are treated the same as other form fields, except they're a file upload object, rather than a string - so you can iterate over the available fields the same as any other POST.

Comment: yes I saw that on the image upload sample, makes sense - but as I don't control the "client" that is posting, I don't know the name of the field (it doesn't show up in .arguments() etc... so not sure where to find it). But for simple cases that looks great.