# How to copy a file via the browser to Amazon S3 using Python (and boto)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto

Creating a file (key) into Amazon S3 using Python (and boto) is not a problem.
With this code, I can connect to a bucket and create a key with a specific content:

```
bucket_instance = connection.get_bucket('bucketname')
key = bucket_instance.new_key('testfile.txt')
key.set_contents_from_string('Content for File')
```

I want to upload a file via the browser (file dialogue) into Amazon S3.

How can I realize this with boto?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with boto, because what you're asking for is purely client-side - there's no direct involvement from the server except to generate the form to post.

What you need to use is Amazon's [browser-based upload with POST](http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html) support. There's a demo of it [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-example-code/post/post_sample.html).

Comment: This is the solution. I didn't know the upload is purely client-side. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this one? [Upload files in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81451/upload-files-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: No, I have an application (python + boto 1.9b) running at Google App Engine. I want to implement, that the users can upload files from their clients into their S3-buckets via a HTML-form (file dialogue).