# Upload a file with web2py on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, upload, web2py

I have a problem deploying my application written in web2py on Google App Engine.
Everything works well on localhost, but on GAE I cannot access the content of an uploaded file.

When I check the request.vars.my_upload_field var on localhost, I get:
FieldStorage('upload_field', 'my_file.txt', 'File content')

But on GAE I only have:
FieldStorage('upload_field', 'my_file.txt')

No file content...
I did not do anything special (I believe...)

Why do I have such behaviour and how to fix it?

PS: I am using a SQLForm(db.my_table) that has an 'upload' field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see detailed instructions for web2py and GAE blobstore upload here: http://web2pyslices.com/main/slices/take_slice/63

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used web2py with GAE, but the [official documentation](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/11#Google-App-Engine)

mentions something about difficulties in uploading files to the app-engine filesystem using web2py. So probably you could instead use GAE's own file-upload abilities like shown in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81451/upload-files-in-google-app-engine/173918#173918)

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, if I want to use google.appengine.ext.webapp, I cannot use web2py framework... isn't it?
For files smaller than 10MB (and mines are smaller than 10KB) it is supposed to work correctly...

Comment: I tried adding at the top of my default.py:
`if request.env.web2py_runtime_gae:
    from google.appengine.ext import webapp
    class GAEHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
        def value(self, v):
            return self.request.get(v)`

And then to call:
`myApp = GAEHandler()
content = myApp.value('my_upload_field')`

But unfortunately it doesn't work...