# Google Cloud Storage in an android app

Tags: android, get, put, bucket, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to put a text document with highscores inside a bucket on the google cloud storage. So far, so good.

Now I want my app to open this textfile in the bucket, check if there is a new highscore, adapt the file and write it back into the bucket.

I´m trying to find example code, since that makes more sense to me for understanding than the apis, but I´m not able to find it.

The answers I get are all, it´s just simple get and put callbacks, but since it ain't simple for me, I was hoping somebody has a link to an example for an android app using google cloud storage and reading and writing online.

I found this information, but would love to see an example for android in eclipse: http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/functions.html

If I'm creating an app in Eclipse, can I use the bucket in the google cloud? Or don't I or future users have access to that bucket for read and write?

Comment: Did you get a Java sample for working with Cloud Storage? I desparately need that now.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Google api client libraries for java.  Google storage has a Json Api (currently in beta and you must email to get turned on).  The client libs are fairly straight forward once you get your head around it.  All google apis are accessed in the same manner.  You can use the Android Tasks example to learn from and apply it to Google Storage Api.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Tasks_API

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to change files, I would advise to use Google Appengine's [Blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Introducing_the_Blobstore) or either save images as [BlobProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81451/upload-files-in-google-app-engine) in GAE. CloudStorage is more for static files, I believe.