# Uploading files in Google App Engine. How to get the file to the upload Handler Class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload

I have a form in google app engine where I want to upload an image and all my text at the same time.  Do I have to seperate this into two seperate pages and actions?

Here is my upload handler:

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def upload(self, reseller_id, imgfile):
        upload_files = imgfile
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        key = blob_info.key()
        r = Reseller.get_by_id(reseller_id)
        r.blob_key_logo = str(key)
        r.put();
```

Here is my creation of a new reseller object:

```
class NewReseller(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.user:
            self.render("new_reseller.html")
        else:
            self.redirect("/display_resellers")

    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get('name')
        website = self.request.get('website')
        information = self.request.get('information')
        address = self.request.get('address')
        city = self.request.get('city')
        state = self.request.get('state')
        zipcode = self.request.get('zipcode')
        email = self.request.get('email')
        phone = self.request.get('phone')

        r = Reseller( name = name, 
              website = website, 
              information = information, 
              address = address,
              city = city,
              state = state,
              zipcode = zipcode,
              email = email, 
              phone = phone)        
        r.put()

        theresellerid = r.key().id()
        #And then Upload the image
        u = UploadHandler()
        logo_img = u.get_uploads('logo_img')
        u.upload(theid, logo_img)

        self.redirect('/display_resellers')
```

I think my problem here is this line:

```
logo_img = u.get_uploads('logo_img')
```

it pops out the error message

```
for key, value in self.request.params.items():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'params'
```

Somehow I need this NewReseller class to inherit the .getuploads from BlobstoreUploadHandler so I can do:

```
   logo_img = self.get_uploads('logo_img')
```

Or there is probably a better way because this seems a little messy.

So my question is how to upload files and data in one form on just one page.  I could do it with two seperate pages.  One for adding the reseller and one for adding the image but that seems over complicated.

I tried to follow some steps and clues from this question:

[Upload files in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81451/upload-files-in-google-app-engine)

******Edit***** Working Implementation Below:

```
class EditReseller(BaseHandler, blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def get(self, reseller_id):
        if self.user:
            reseller = Reseller.get_by_id(int(reseller_id))
            upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
            image = True
            if reseller.blob_key_logo is None:
                image = False
            self.render('edit_reseller.html', r=reseller, reseller_id=reseller_id, upload_url=upload_url, image=image)

        else:
            self.redirect('/admin')


class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        reseller_id = self.request.get('reseller_id')
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('logo_img')
        if upload_files:
            blob_info = upload_files[0]
            key = blob_info.key()
            r = Reseller.get_by_id(int(reseller_id))
            r.blob_key_logo = str(key)
            r.put();

        name = self.request.get('name')
        website = self.request.get('website')
        information = self.request.get('information')
        address = self.request.get('address')
        city = self.request.get('city')
        state = self.request.get('state')
        zipcode = self.request.get('zipcode')
        email = self.request.get('email')
        phone = self.request.get('phone')

        if name and website and information and email and phone and address and city and state and zipcode:
            r = Reseller.get_by_id(int(reseller_id))
            r.name = name 
            r.website = website
            r.information = information
            r.address = address
            r.city = city
            r.state = state
            r.zipcode = zipcode
            r.email = email
            r.phone = phone
            r.put()

        else:
            error = "Looks like your missing some critical info"
            self.render("edit_reseller.html", name=name, website=website, information=information, address=address, city=city, zipcode=zipcode, email=email, phone=phone, error=error)


        self.redirect("/edit_reseller/" + reseller_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put the logic of the UploadHandler inside the Reseller(BaseHandler) and make Reseller inherit from blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler.

The call to get_uploads fails, as the NewReseller Class does not inherit from BlobstoreUploadHandler. The BlobstoreUploadHandler class takes over the upload operation so you do not need to create a post method, just add the corresponding logic from post ( `name = self.request.get('name')`, `r = Reseller()`, `r.put()`, etc. ) and add it to the upload method.

You should not call or create a new a handler instance by hand (unless you know what you are doing), as it would be missing the things that make it work.

The [complete app sample](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Complete_Sample_App) at the official docs, might also be helpful.

Comment: Thank You.  I changed the EditReseller Class to inherit from my base handler and blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler and moved the entire post method to the upload handler.