# GAE - Uploading an image from a mobile device to blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have successfully been able to upload images to my Google App Engine Blobstore using the provided code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81451/upload-files-in-google-app-engine) (in one of the comments, which is majorly based on the GAE docs).

Here is the full code for reference:

```
import os
import urllib

from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
        self.response.out.write("""Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>""")

        for b in blobstore.BlobInfo.all():
            self.response.out.write('<li><a href="/serve/%s' % str(b.key()) + '">' + str(b.filename) + '</a>')

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        self.redirect('/')

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, blob_key):
        blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
        if not blobstore.get(blob_key):
            self.error(404)
        else:
            self.send_blob(blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key), save_as=True)

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
          [('/', MainHandler),
           ('/upload', UploadHandler),
           ('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler),
          ], debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

However, this code requires that the upload url be created on a `GET` request prior to `POST` request containing the image data:

```
def get(self):
  upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
```

When I try to send the image from a mobile device, I'd like to push the server code into a single code-block under the `def post(self):` function, and I'm having trouble doing this.

Moving the above line into the `def post(self):` code doesn't seem to do the trick.

**Any ideas?**

Cheers!
Brett

Answer (score 2):

yes you can make it one single block of code using urlfetch. Here is my approach:

```python
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        if len(upload_files) > 0 :
            blob_info = upload_files[0]
            self.response.write(str(blob_info.key()))
        else:
            self.error(404) 

class SomeHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        file = self.request.POST.get('file')
        if (file is not None):
            # Use urlfetch to call to the blob upload url and get result
            # Just copy the same request body and header and pass to UploadHandler here
            result = urlfetch.fetch(
                url= blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload'),
                payload=self.request.body,
                method=urlfetch.POST,
                headers=self.request.headers)
            if result.status_code == 200:
                blob_key_str = result.content
                # Get blob key
                blob_key = blobstore.BlobKey(blob_key_str)
                # Maybe a url for the file
                blob_url = images.get_serving_url(blob_key_str, 400)
```

This way you can always Upload file to SomeHandler rather than have to obtain the upload URL first then only Upload.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi. This solution works properly on localhost, but doesn't work o when uploaded on Google server. Any ideas ?

Comment: It works in my case, you gotta check your log. There could be other problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work with the default Blobstore upload handler: it needs two requests: first to create a one-time download url and the second to actually do POST to this url.

If you want to do all in one go, create your own [file upload handler](http://blog.thomnichols.org/2009/12/restful-file-upload-for-appengine) and use new Blobstore API to [write files](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore).