# how to render django template from code instead of file on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-templates, webapp2

I am writing a Google App Engine webapp that renders some html to a Django template. I want to either render the template using either a file or just some json thats very similar to that in file. Is it possible to use Django to render this to a file that is read in and stored in database? 
The oldAPI.HTML is just an old version of api.html but with some small changes. Rendering Django to the api-html file works fine.

I understand that you can't store files on GAE, how can i dynamically use Django to render to HTML stored in memory?

```
path = ""
oldAPI = APIVersion().get_by_key_name(version)
if oldAPI is None:
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "api.html")
template_values = {
            'responseDict': responseDict,
            }
        if path:
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
        else:
            self.response.out.write(template.render(oldAPI.html,template_values))
```

Comment: You can store files in the blobstore http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81451/upload-files-in-google-app-engine

Comment: Yes, but then i'll have to make a Template from the read file. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to render a template 'in memory', there are a few things you'll need to do:

## App Engine Setup

First of all, you'll need to ensure that everything is set up correctly for Django. There's a lot of information [on the Third-party libraries page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries#Django), but I'll include it here for your benefit.

In `main.py`, or (whatever your script handler is), you'll need to add the following lines:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2') # Change to a different version as you like
```

Don't forget to include `django` in your `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:
    - name: django
      version: "1.2"
```

## Code Setup

Second of all, you'll need to create a `Template` object, as denoted in the [Google App Engine template documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates). For example:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

# Your code...
template_string = "Hello World"
my_template = template.Template(template_string)

# `context` is optional, but will be useful!
# `context` is what will contain any variables, etc. you use in the template
rendered_output = template.render(context)

# Now, do what you like with `rendered_output`!
```

Comment: When i try this i get the error: AssertionError: settings has not been configured in this thread. Is there some kind of setting i need to enable as well?

Comment: You may need to create a simple `settings.py` file in the same folder as `app.yaml`. [This article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/django) has an example `settings.py` file you can use. I recognize the article is out of date, but *that* information should still be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can instantiate a template from text in Django with just `template.Template(my_text)`.

Comment: I'm getting AssertionError: settings has not been configured in this thread when i try to instantiate temlate from text. Tried with the html and template.Template("hello world")

Comment: Maybe just try to use StringIO?

Comment: Whats the syntax for using that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no (*builtin*) way to do so, but you can get inspired from the function [google.appengine.ext.webapp.template._load_user_django](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py#95) (GAE with Python 2.5) or [google.appengine.ext.webapp.template._load_internal_django](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py#138) (GAE with Python 2.7) and write your very own wrapper overriding settings and rendering like GAE source does.