# Google App Engine (Python) get file contents

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am writing a web app and I need to read a text file that a user will upload.

I will not need to store it in a database; the app only performs simple operations on the text in the file.

I'm currently uploading the file with <input type=file" name="input_file" id="file-in"> in a form submitted via POST and running this in main.py:

```
user_file = self.request.get("input_file")
print user_file
print type(user_file)
```

Output when I tried to upload a file ("foo.txt") with the contents "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!":

```
foo.txt
<type 'unicode'>
```

Why did this happen? How can I access the *contents* of the file?

Any help is appreciated.  If you need some background info, I wrote [this simple encryptor/decryptor app](http://nc-cipher.appspot.com/), and I'm trying to add the ability to upload a file instead of just copy-pasting the text in.

Answer (score 1):

Give your `input` a name:

```
<input type="file" name="input_file"/>
```

and then use the name rather than `input` in your call to `request.get()`:

```
user_file = self.request.get("input_file")
```

See also: [Upload files in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81451/290085)

Comment: Oops! That was actually an error in my question asking– I will edit the question now.  I had `<input type="file" name="input" id="file-in">`; I changed it to `<input type="file" name="input_file" id="file-in">` and adjusted my call to `request.get()`.  Nothing changed.

Comment: Suggestion: Carefully check the rest of your code against the good answers in the "See also" link I provided ([Upload files in Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81451/upload-files-in-google-app-engine)).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
user_file = self.request.get("input")
print user_file
print type(user_file)

print user_file.decode('utf-8')
print type(user_file.decode('utf-8'))
```